# Batch printing ggmaps

Tags: r, lapply, ggmap

Consider a list of 1,000 ggmaps. Let's call this list `maps`.

How can we print them as .png to the working directory?

The code I'm using for a single ggmap is:

```
png(filename = "1.png",width=1000, height=1000)
m1<-ggmap(maps[[1]])

print(m1)
dev.off()
```

I was considering using `lapply` for something like this:

```r
lapply(maps, function (x) png(filename = "x.png", width=1000, height=1000) x
<-ggmap(maps[[x]]) print(x) dev.off() )
```

Or a `for`,

```
for (x in maps) { png(filename = "x.png", width=1000, height=1000) 
x <-ggmap(maps[[x]]) print(x) dev.off()}
```

However, I feel this is wrong because of the `filename=`argument. I am unsure of how to assign element x of the list to it because of the quotes.

I wish not to break the R Session and have to terminate it because it has taken about two hours to and my API queries to get that list of 1,000 ggmaps.

Comment: `?\`for\`` / `?seq_along` + you can use `save.image()` if you want to preserve all the objects in the event you break your session.

Comment: @hrbrmstr yes, I know. But I don't know what to write in the filename bit so it also takes in the `x`. For example, `for (x in maps) { png(filename = "x.png", width=1000, height=1000) x
<-ggmap(maps[[x]]) print(x) dev.off()}` but because the `"x.png"` is in quotes I don't know if this will change the name for each image. What should I do for the `filename` argument please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `for` and `seq_along` as suggested. In the end with the help of the package `stringr`.

```html
for (i in seq_along(maps)) {
  filename <-str_c(i,".png")
  png(filename = filename,width=1000, height=1000) 
m <-ggmap(maps[[i]]) 
print(m)
dev.off()
```